# '=' is not the same as '=' | Declaration Reference Link - don't know how to call this

Tags: powershell

I don't understand the behaviour of the following PowerShell code example.

```
$a=1..3
$b=$a
$b[0]="1000"
$a

$c = "Cat"
$d=$c
$d="Dog"
$c

$e=1..3
$f=$e+4
$f[0]="1000"
$e
```

The commandline result for this is:

```
1000
2
3

Cat

1
2
3
```

Why do I have in the first part something like a 'link'. `$b` seems to be a link to `$a`. So if I change `$b`, it seems that `$a` was changed for real.

In part two `$c` and `$d` are two different Variables but I think I made the same like in part one. Why I have two different variables here and not an 'link'?

And in part three I do the same as in part one but add a `+1`. Now I don't have a 'link'. I have again two different variables.

Can anyone tell me what the difference between these examples is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example shows that modifying part of an object doesn't change references.

The second and third examples show that assigning a new object doesn't change other references to the previous objects.

In more detail:

```
$a=1..3
```

`$a` is a reference to a (new) array of three integers.

```
$b=$a
```

`$b` references the same array object.

```
$b[0]="1000"
```

A value in the array is changed

```
$a
```

And that change is visible to other references to the same array.

Example two:

```
$c = "Cat"
```

`$c` is a reference to a new string object.

```
$d=$c
```

`$d` is now a reference to the same string object

```
$d="Dog"
```

But it is now a reference to a different string object.

```
$c
```

And this last assignment does not change which string object `$c` references.

(The third example is the same thing, with `$f=$e+4` creating a new array object.)

Comment: okay. thx. i understand a bit more now. +1. but what i don't understand: why $b[0]="1000" changes something in the array while $d="Dog" creates a reference to a new string object. i can't see the exact difference between these two lines... for me it is the same thing...

Comment: @frupfrup It's hard to explain for me because changing part of an object (via index on array or property name) to be is clearly changing part of the same object (there is more than a simple name on the left hand side) is different from a new object (just a name on the left hand side). What is perhaps not clear is that each distinct string (whether literal or an operation on another string) is a different object.

Comment: It depends on the object type.  Primitive types likes strings and ints are passed by value.  Array and objects are passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case:

```
$b[0]="1000"
```

modifies the object that `$b` and also `$a` refer to.

In the second:

```
$d="Dog"
```

assigns a new value to `$d` so that it no longer refers to the same value as `$c`.